# call a method inside a ngFor in my html (angular6)

Tags: angular6, ngfor

I'm new to stackOverflow, couldn't find an answer to my question.
I'm trying to use an ngFor inside an ngFor.
Is it possible to call a method inside an *ngFor: 
something like this :

```
    <div *ngFor="let nbStar of myMethod(skill.level)">
```

where myMethod is using data from my first ngFor as parameter to generate an array of numbers.

my code:

```
<div *ngFor="let skill of skills">
        <div class="picture">
            <img src="{{skill.skillPicture}}"/>
        </div>  
      <div class="title-skill">
        <h3>{{skill.skillName | uppercase}} </h3>
        Niveau: 
        <div *ngFor="let nbStar of generateStarsArray(skill.level)">
           <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks a lot for any clues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you could use it. but make sure your method returns always an array.

For the following template

```
<div *ngFor="let skill of skills">
    <div class="picture">
        <img src="{{skill.skillPicture}}"/>
    </div>  
  <div class="title-skill">
    <h3>{{skill.skillName | uppercase}} </h3>
    Niveau: 
    <div *ngFor="let nbStar of generateStarsArray(skill.level)">
       <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

in component.ts method `generateStarsArray` should be something like below

```
 public generateStarsArray(level): Array<any> {
     let stars = [];
     //---> some logic
     return stars;
 }
```

Comment: Its my pleasure, does it worth of getting up vote and approve?

Comment: yes of course man, sorry i didn't know how to do that, it's done now, but apparently I can't give you an up vote cause my reputation is too low or something!!